# React 17: "useEffect has missing dependencies" with useMutation function

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm learning react query and the following code is working as expecting but I have this warning message:

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'code' and 'mutate'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

But if I add 'code' and 'mutate' in the dependency array I have an infinite loop.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";
import * as api from "../api/api";

const getQuery = () => {
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  return queryParams.get("code");
};

const Authentication = () => {
  const [code] = useState(getQuery());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (code) {
      mutate.mutate(code);
    }
  }, []);

  const auth = async () => {
    window.location.href = `https://www.betaseries.com/authorize?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&scope=&redirect_uri=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_CALLBACK}`;
  };

  const mutate = useMutation(api.access_token, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem("isAuth", data.data.access_token);
    },
  });

  return <button onClick={auth}>Login</button>;
};

export default Authentication;
```

Short explanation of what I did:

1. User click on login button, he is redirected to the website to enter his login / password

```js
const auth = async () => {
    window.location.href = `https://www.betaseries.com/authorize?client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&scope=&redirect_uri=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_CALLBACK}`;
  };
```

2. After a success login he is redirected to my website with a url params ?code=xxx
3. I catch the code and use it to call a route that will provide me his access_token

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (code) {
      mutate.mutate(code);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: This code runs twice on  ` <React.StrictMode>`  do you get error as `mutate` runs twice in `useEffect`?  @jeyremd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mutate function itself is stable, but the object returned from useMutation is not. If you destruct, you can add it to your dependency array:

```
const { mutate } = useMutation(…)
```

Comment: This is not mentioned in the doc, please add it.

Comment: please feel free to open a PR to the docs - this is open source :)

Comment: @TkDodo PR opened: https://github.com/TanStack/query/pull/5702